# Python group by 2 columns, output multiple columns

Tags: python

I have a tab-delimited file with movie genre and year in 2 columns:

```
Comedy  2013
Comedy  2014
Drama   2012
Mystery 2011
Comedy  2013
Comedy  2013
Comedy  2014
Comedy  2013
News    2012
Sport   2012
Sci-Fi  2013
Comedy  2014
Family  2013
Comedy  2013
Drama   2013
Biography   2013
```

I want to group the genres together by year and print out in the following format (does not have to be in alphabetical order):

```
Year    2011    2012    2013    2014
Biography   0   0   1   0
Comedy  0   0   5   3
Drama   0   1   1   0   
Family      0   0   1   0
Mystery 1   0   0   0
News    0   1   0   0
Sci-Fi  0   0   1   0
Sport   0   1   0   0
```

How should I approach it? At the moment I'm creating my output through MS Excel, but I would like to do it through Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like to use `pandas`, you can do it as follows:

```py
from collections import Counter

# load file
with open('tab.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')

# replace separating whitespace with exactly one space
lines = [' '.join(l.split()) for l in lines]

# find all years and genres
genres = sorted(set(l.split()[0] for l in lines))
years = sorted(set(l.split()[1] for l in lines))

# count genre-year combinations
C = Counter(lines)

# print table
print "Year".ljust(10),
for y in years:
    print y.rjust(6),
print
for g in genres:
    print g.ljust(10),
    for y in years:
        print `C[g + ' ' + y]`.rjust(6),
    print
```

The most interesting function is probably `Counter`, which counts the number of occurrences of each element. To make sure that the length of the separating whitespace does not influence the counting, I replace it with a single space beforehand.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way do to this is using the `pandas` library, which provides lots of way of interacting with tables of data:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(names=['genre', 'year'])
df.pivot_table(index='genre', columns='year', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
year       2011  2012  2013  2014
genre                            
Biography     0     0     1     0
Comedy        0     0     5     3
Drama         0     1     1     0
Family        0     0     1     0
Mystery       1     0     0     0
News          0     1     0     0
Sci-Fi        0     0     1     0
Sport         0     1     0     0
```

If you're only just starting with Python, you might find trying to learn `pandas` is a bit too much on top of learning the language, but once you have some Python knowledge, `pandas` provides very intuitive ways to interact with data.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the pandas library.